# URI for CloudBlockBlob is giving special characters in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have simple code which interacts with Azure Blob as below.
I want to get the URL where I'm uploading the file.
Say suppose if in my blob storage , I have a container, in which there are multiple folders, I need to get the path of the file.So to get that I'm trying to use the blockBlob.Uri paramter.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            string   storageAccConnString = "Connection string";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = "Account Name";
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            string folderPath    "Folder1" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Folder2" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Folder3";
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(folderPath);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Local system filePath which needs to be uploaded to Blob");
            Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri);
            Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri.OriginalString);
            Console.ReadLine();  
            // I didnt write the upload code as my question was regarding URI
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the response for this, but instead of folder seperators like "`/`" or "`\`" , I'm getting `%5C` .

> URI :
>   https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/Folder1%5CFolder2%5Folder3/Test.zip

How do I rectify this.Any help would be useful.Thanks.

Comment: That's the way that URIs embed special characters. They should be decoded just fine at the far end.

Comment: @SteveTodd , I'm able to upload the file. I do not face any issue in that. I have to print the URI as well for logging purpose. And I'm unable to get the correct URI with special characters. I do not want to use String.Replace method also.

Comment: @CrazyCoder *those* are the correct URL characters. In any case there are no folders in **any** cloud storage provider - not AWS, Google or Azure. All are flat containers with blobs whose name is the string that comes after the container URL. Blobs are *emulated* in AWS and Azure by treating some characters like folder separators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a few issues with your code:

- First, blob storage has 2 level hierarchy: container and blob. The way you're creating a reference for container is incorrect. Because your container name contains a URL reserved character (`\`), it is getting URL encoded as `%5C`.
- Next, If you want to upload a file inside a virtual folder inside a container, you will need to append the path of the virtual folder to the name of the blob. For example, let's say you have a blob container called `files` and you want to upload a file called `myfile.txt` but place it inside `Folder1/Folder2/Folder3` virtual folder, this is how you would do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{         
    string   storageAccConnString = "Connection string";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = "Account Name";
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();       
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference('files');
    var blobName = "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3" + "myfile.txt";
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri);
    Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("URI : " + blockBlob.Uri.OriginalString);
    Console.ReadLine();  
    // I didnt write the upload code as my question was regarding URI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blob storage does not really use folders and subfolders. It just uses the file path as the full file name. All you have is your container as a separation mechanism.
You can upload files with folder separators in them, but it won't really do much, even though file browsers that support blob storage will usually emulate the folders.
You can emulate the location of a file simply by including the file path in the filename.
Want to move a file to a different directory? Just rename the file path, etc.

If you want, you can decode the URL in the following way:

```
    string input = "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/Folder1%5CFolder2%5Folder3/Test.zip";
    string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);
    Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears that you're using `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` which (according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.8)) will:

> Provide a platform-specific character used to separate directory levels in a path string that reflects a hierarchical file system organization.

When run on a Windows system, the `DirectorySeparatorChar` is `\` while on a Linux system it is `/`.

When making requests to web services, the path separator used for URIs is `/` while `\` is considered an unsafe character and requires encoding - hence the `%5C` you're seeing.

To fix the problem you're facing, the easiest solution would be to simply replace your usage of `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` with `"/"`.

```cs
string folderPath = "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're asking for a Container reference with directory separators in them. A container is only meant to be used to group blobs together on the root level.

> A container organizes a set of blobs, similar to a directory in a file system. A storage account can include an unlimited number of containers, and a container can store an unlimited number of blobs.

Source: [Introduction to Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction)

Blobs can have directory separators in them, organizing them in virtual folders *inside of a container*.

For more information on how to do this, see [Creating an Azure Blob Hierarchy](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip79.html)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure when you save file like this:

```
Stream str
...
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(changePathCharacters(physicalRoute) + fileName);                        

blob.UploadFromStream(str);
```

**physicalRoute** has not `\\` for folder separator, it must have `/` separator:

```
private static string changePathCharacters(string path)
        {

            return path.Replace(@"\", @"/");
        }
```

Then in `blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri` you will have something like this:

`https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/Folder1/Folder/Folder3/Test.zip`